# Shiny slider crashing R code using leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, statistics, leaflet

I am writing a Shiny app using leaflet to plot different points based on slider values. My relevant Shiny/leaflet code is shown below:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  subsetData1 <- reactive({
    District25_NoPaperBallot %>% 
      filter(District25_NoPaperBallot$Difference >= as.numeric(input$slider1[1]) &
               District25_NoPaperBallot$Difference <= as.numeric(input$slider1[2]))
  })
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = District25_NoPaperBallot) %>%
      setView(lng =-87.3633, lat=36.1490 , zoom = 8) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(~ District25_NoPaperBallot$Longitude, ~District25_NoPaperBallot$Latitude, 
                 popup = as.character(District25_NoPaperBallot$PRECINCT),
                 label = ~as.character(District25_NoPaperBallot$PRECINCT),
                 radius = 5)
  })
  observe({
    leafletProxy("map", data = subsetData1()) %>%
      clearMarkers() %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(lng = ~ Longitude, lat = ~ Latitude,
                        popup = as.character(District25_NoPaperBallot$PRECINCT),
                        label = ~as.character(District25_NoPaperBallot$PRECINCT),
                        radius = 5)

  }

  )
}
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel( sliderInput(inputId = "slider1", label = "Difference", 
                min = min(District25_NoPaperBallot$Difference),
                max = max(District25_NoPaperBallot$Difference),
                value = c(min(District25_NoPaperBallot$Difference),
                          max(District25_NoPaperBallot$Difference)))
                ),
  mainPanel(leafletOutput("map"))
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run the app from RStudio, the page won't load and crashes immediately. The following errors are output:

```
Warning in data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'metaData' applied to an object of class "c('mts', 'ts')"
```

Where am I going wrong? Any tips on what to change? I appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Can you please add some data (or a location where to download the data)?

Comment: And - just from a superficial analysis of your code, there is nothing triggering the execution of your Observe: no reactive event that triggers its execution. The reactive `subsetData1()` won't suffice for this. Try to add on top of the observe() code `input$slider1` : this will trigger its execution...

Comment: Enzo -- Thank you for the recommendations! I was able to figure it out, I just reworked it from the start and got it  working.